# Strange 1px bug in Firefox with bootstrap.css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with a styling. By default it renders great both in Chrome and Firefox. When I add Twitter Bootstrap stylesheet to the document, **text in table cells gets moved by 1px in Firefox**. However I am not even adding Bootstrap's ".table" class to my table. I tested different cases and it seems that it caused by something global in bootstrap.css. It also related to line-height.

I have added css snippet like this, but it didn't help.

```
.my-table *,
.my-table *:before,
.my-table *:after {
    line-height: 14px !important;
}
```

It gets really strange, because when I add a global line-height fix, my table finally renders properly. Also when adding this line-height rule only to body or table, it has no effect.

```
* {
    line-height: 14px !important;
}
```

I have attached a screenshot that illustrates the 1px problem.

[image: bootstrap bug]

I tried comparing both versions with devtools and similar approaches, but there doesn't seem to be any difference between styles applied to the table (with or without boostrap). Also checked computed styles.

Comment: without your table to fiddle with I can't say, but they also use normalize.css so this table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 0;
} is in there. Try line-height:normal

Comment: Are you using vertical-align:middle on the td?

Comment: I am using vertical-align:top and padding from top, because vertical-align:middle was imprecise on Firefox (Chrome was ok). I will try to create a minimal example and put it on fiddle.

The default table styles from normalize.css was not causing the issue, already checked that.

Comment: Remove the line height on body line-height: 1.42857143 and see what happens

Comment: Thanks for your idea, @Christina, it actually helped me to solve the problem. I started removing line-heights from bootstrap.css and found out that removing line-height from h1 element fixes the problem. However this is really strange. The h1 element wasn't even in the table, but above it and in a separate wrapper. The 1px bug can be fixed by either removing ``line-height: 1.1`` from h1 or by removing the h1 altogether.

Comment: Try clearing your table. Clear both. Weird it should be a block element and not inherit. Everything was closed?

Comment: Yep, everything was closed and no floats were involved. Just checked with w3 validator and HTML is valid too. I am really confused about this. Also this occurs only with Firefox. You can check that live - http://datazenit.com/static/sensei-grid/examples/ Try adding ``line-height:normal`` to the h1 element. It is hard to see at first, because it is just 1px change, but if you toggle that line-height option you will notice the difference.